# How to easily verify correct npm dependencies installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I know when to prompt user to run `npm install` if there are any unmet package.json dependencies?

I would like to do this, because if any `require()` fails, the user gets a poor error message:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'nopt'
```

I've previously tried to just check for the existence of a `node_modules` directory, but this only works effectively for fresh git clones.  I've also tried just requiring `npm` and running `npm install` as part of load, but that is very heavy weight.

I'm hoping there is a lighter weight library out there that just parses `package.json` and makes sure `node_modules` contents satisfy the requirements.

One idea was to use `process.on('uncaughtException')` to catch only module import errors, but looking to see if there is a "standard" solution first.

Comment: Iterate through `node_modules`, parse the `version` in their `package.json` and compare with your own `package.json`?

Comment: there is not effective way of doing this, `npm install` takes cares of all modules dependencies, i don't see how it supposed to throw error about loading modules in your npm package. There is optional dependencies if thats what you are looking for ..

Comment: Look at [grunt-check-dependencies](https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-check-dependencies/blob/master/tasks/lib/check-dependencies.js). If you're using grunt, you're pretty much done.  If not, replacing the grunt file/console calls with node fs/console shouldn't take long.

Comment: My use case is: I'm getting error reports from users who run my script forgetting to update node_modules.  I am delivering the package via `npm` which handles this automatically, but these reports are coming from users using `git clone` to test unreleased versions.  So, any solution that requires tools outside of the node script itself won't work (i.e. no grunt).  However, its possible I could create a node package as @jbillich suggests, perhaps using the grunt script as a starting point.  Was hoping this already existed, though.

Comment: I would like to see this, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found this today. Not sure if your still need this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-dependencies

```
npm install check-dependencies --save-dev
```

Install this package and save to your package.json.

```
require('check-dependencies')(config, callback);
```

config is the following object, which is then passed to the callback.

```
{
    status: number,      // 0 if successful, 1 otherwise
    depsWereOk: boolean, // true if dependencies were already satisfied
    log: array,          // array of logged messages
    error: array,        // array of logged errors
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `yarn` and do `yarn check --verify-tree` (you can continue using `npm` for everything else)

Answer (score 5):

`npm ls` will report missing packages when run from the project folder.

[npm-ls documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

This might have issues if you're using git dependencies, though. (Thanks @gman).

Comment: This actually fails. type `git clone somerepo; cd somerepo; npm install; rm -rf node_modules/somedep; npm ls` doesn't notice the dep is missing. Even just `git clone somerepo; cd somerepo; npm ls` does not report anything missing

Comment: neither of these fail for me. can you give the repo you used where it failed? i'm using npm 6.14.4

Comment: It looks like it fails with git based dependencies. `npm install --save git+https://github.com/someperson/somerepo.git#v1.2.3` now delete `node_modules/somerepo` and `npm ls` will not notice it's gone but `npm install` will

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
function dependenciesNeedUpdating() {
  const childProcess = require('child_process');
  const result = JSON.parse(childProcess.execSync('npm install --dry-run --json').toString());
  return result.added.length > 0 || result.updated.length > 0 || result.removed > 0;
}
```

Call it like this

```
if (dependenciesNeedUpdating()) {
  console.error('dependencies need updating. Please run `npm install`');
  process.exit(1);
}
```

If you want to install this as a dependency  its 5 lines are in an npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ld-check-dependencies). It adds a `ld-check-dependencies` command (the 4 usage lines above) so you can use it directly in your npm scripts. Example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ld-check-dependencies && rollup ..."
  },
```

---

### Rationale:

I'm learning that dependencies are a huge liability and should be avoided any time there is a simpler solution.

For example here's is the ridiculous dependency tree for [check-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-dependencies)

```
└─┬ check-dependencies@1.1.0
  ├─┬ bower-config@1.4.3
  │ ├── graceful-fs@4.2.4
  │ ├── minimist@0.2.1 extraneous
  │ ├── mout@1.2.2
  │ ├─┬ osenv@0.1.5
  │ │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.2
  │ │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2
  │ ├─┬ untildify@2.1.0
  │ │ └── os-homedir@1.0.2 deduped
  │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
  ├─┬ chalk@2.4.2
  │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@3.2.1
  │ │ └─┬ color-convert@1.9.3
  │ │   └── color-name@1.1.3
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ └─┬ supports-color@5.5.0
  │   └── has-flag@3.0.0
  ├─┬ findup-sync@2.0.0
  │ ├── detect-file@1.0.0
  │ ├─┬ is-glob@3.1.0
  │ │ └── is-extglob@2.1.1
  │ ├─┬ micromatch@3.1.10
  │ │ ├── arr-diff@4.0.0
  │ │ ├── array-unique@0.3.2
  │ │ ├─┬ braces@2.3.2
  │ │ │ ├── arr-flatten@1.1.0
  │ │ │ ├── array-unique@0.3.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├─┬ fill-range@4.0.0
  │ │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ is-number@3.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ └── kind-of@3.2.2 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── repeat-string@1.6.1
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ to-regex-range@2.1.1
  │ │ │ │   ├── is-number@3.0.0 deduped
  │ │ │ │   └── repeat-string@1.6.1 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── isobject@3.0.1
  │ │ │ ├── repeat-element@1.1.3
  │ │ │ ├── snapdragon@0.8.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├─┬ snapdragon-node@2.1.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── define-property@1.0.0 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ snapdragon-util@3.0.1
  │ │ │ │   └── kind-of@3.2.2 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├─┬ split-string@3.1.0
  │ │ │ │ └── extend-shallow@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ └── to-regex@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ define-property@2.0.2
  │ │ │ ├── is-descriptor@1.0.2 extraneous
  │ │ │ └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ extend-shallow@3.0.2
  │ │ │ ├── assign-symbols@1.0.0
  │ │ │ └── is-extendable@1.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ ├─┬ extglob@2.0.4
  │ │ │ ├── array-unique@0.3.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── define-property@1.0.0 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├─┬ expand-brackets@2.1.4
  │ │ │ │ ├── debug@2.6.9 deduped
  │ │ │ │ ├── define-property@0.2.5 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── posix-character-classes@0.1.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── regex-not@1.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ │ ├── snapdragon@0.8.2 deduped
  │ │ │ │ └── to-regex@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├── fragment-cache@0.2.1 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── regex-not@1.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── snapdragon@0.8.2 deduped
  │ │ │ └── to-regex@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ fragment-cache@0.2.1
  │ │ │ └── map-cache@0.2.2
  │ │ ├── kind-of@6.0.3
  │ │ ├─┬ nanomatch@1.2.13
  │ │ │ ├── arr-diff@4.0.0 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── array-unique@0.3.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── define-property@2.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── fragment-cache@0.2.1 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── is-windows@1.0.2
  │ │ │ ├── kind-of@6.0.3 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── object.pick@1.3.0 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── regex-not@1.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── snapdragon@0.8.2 deduped
  │ │ │ └── to-regex@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ object.pick@1.3.0
  │ │ │ └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ ├─┬ regex-not@1.0.2
  │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │ │ └─┬ safe-regex@1.1.0
  │ │ │   └── ret@0.1.15
  │ │ ├─┬ snapdragon@0.8.2
  │ │ │ ├─┬ base@0.11.2
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ cache-base@1.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ collection-visit@1.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ map-visit@1.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── object-visit@1.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ object-visit@1.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │   └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── component-emitter@1.3.0 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── get-value@2.0.6
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-value@1.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── get-value@2.0.6 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-values@1.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── is-number@3.0.0 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── kind-of@4.0.0 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ set-value@2.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── is-extendable@0.1.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ is-plain-object@2.0.4
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── split-string@3.1.0 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ to-object-path@0.3.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── kind-of@3.2.2 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ union-value@1.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── arr-union@3.1.0 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── get-value@2.0.6 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── is-extendable@0.1.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── set-value@2.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ unset-value@1.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │   ├── has-value@0.3.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │   └── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ class-utils@0.3.6
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── arr-union@3.1.0
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── define-property@0.2.5 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ static-extend@0.1.2
  │ │ │ │ │   ├── define-property@0.2.5 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │   └─┬ object-copy@0.1.0
  │ │ │ │ │     ├── copy-descriptor@0.1.1
  │ │ │ │ │     ├── define-property@0.2.5 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ │     └── kind-of@3.2.2 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── component-emitter@1.3.0
  │ │ │ │ ├── define-property@1.0.0 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ ├── isobject@3.0.1 deduped
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ mixin-deep@1.3.2
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── for-in@1.0.2
  │ │ │ │ │ └── is-extendable@1.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ │ └── pascalcase@0.1.1
  │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
  │ │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0
  │ │ │ ├── define-property@0.2.5 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├── extend-shallow@2.0.1 extraneous
  │ │ │ ├── map-cache@0.2.2 deduped
  │ │ │ ├── source-map@0.5.7
  │ │ │ ├─┬ source-map-resolve@0.5.3
  │ │ │ │ ├── atob@2.1.2
  │ │ │ │ ├── decode-uri-component@0.2.0
  │ │ │ │ ├── resolve-url@0.2.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── source-map-url@0.4.0
  │ │ │ │ └── urix@0.1.0
  │ │ │ └── use@3.1.1
  │ │ └─┬ to-regex@3.0.2
  │ │   ├── define-property@2.0.2 deduped
  │ │   ├── extend-shallow@3.0.2 deduped
  │ │   ├── regex-not@1.0.2 deduped
  │ │   └── safe-regex@1.1.0 deduped
  │ └─┬ resolve-dir@1.0.1
  │   ├─┬ expand-tilde@2.0.2
  │   │ └─┬ homedir-polyfill@1.0.3
  │   │   └── parse-passwd@1.0.0
  │   └─┬ global-modules@1.0.0
  │     ├─┬ global-prefix@1.0.2
  │     │ ├── expand-tilde@2.0.2 deduped
  │     │ ├── homedir-polyfill@1.0.3 deduped
  │     │ ├── ini@1.3.5
  │     │ ├── is-windows@1.0.2 deduped
  │     │ └─┬ which@1.3.1
  │     │   └── isexe@2.0.0
  │     ├── is-windows@1.0.2 deduped
  │     └── resolve-dir@1.0.1 deduped
  ├── lodash.camelcase@4.3.0
  ├── minimist@1.2.5
  └── semver@5.7.1
```

788 js files and 48000 lines of code.

Everyone one of those dependencies is another chance for you to be told something is broke, deprecated, there's a new vulnerability, etc. Basically by using something with so many dependencies you're adding to your workload when you could instead be spending time shipping, dancing, playing with your kids, whatever. You thought you were saving time by using a dependency but if it's got so many dependencies than you're not saving time if you compare to a lower or *simple* no dependency option because you will be forever dealing with the issues of those dependencies.

Here's the dependency tree for [deps-ok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deps-ok) which is much more reasonable.

```
└─┬ deps-ok@1.4.1
  ├── check-more-types@2.24.0
  ├─┬ debug@3.1.0
  │ └── ms@2.0.0
  ├── lazy-ass@1.6.0
  ├── lodash@4.17.10
  ├── minimist@1.2.0
  ├─┬ q@2.0.3
  │ ├── asap@2.0.6
  │ ├── pop-iterate@1.0.1
  │ └── weak-map@1.0.5
  ├── quote@0.4.0
  └── semver@5.5.0
```

But it still manages to demonstrate the problem with dependencies

```
❯ npm audit
                                                                                
                       === npm audit security report ===                        
                                                                                
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.11                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ deps-ok                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ deps-ok > lodash                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/782                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.12                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ deps-ok                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ deps-ok > lodash                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1065                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.19                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ deps-ok                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ deps-ok > lodash                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimist                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=0.2.1 <1.0.0 || >=1.2.3                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ deps-ok                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ deps-ok > minimist                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 4 vulnerabilities (2 low, 2 high) in 13 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Now of course maybe you don't care about those vulnerabilities because this script is only used during building but now you have a new problem that any real vulnerabilities will be buried in these ones you don't care about.

I have no idea how robust or comprehensive the solution above is. The good thing is it relies on `npm` so whatever `npm install` is going to do it's doing that exact thing.

Comment: Nice solution. The downside is that `npm install` takes a while to run. `deps-ok` is super fast and you can hook it before any script without noticeable delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is npm way to do it, but just found this seems helpful:

blog post: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/check-dependencies-in-grunt-by-default.html

project: https://github.com/bahmutov/deps-ok

Comment: Please try not to post link-only answers, since the linked content may be removed at any time.

Comment: @DavidPärsson not sure, what am I supposed to do? copy the project description? The original poster asks exactly for the library like this.

Comment: When reading your answer, it's not clear to me that the project solves the issue. I'm guessing that the content behind the first link states that, but that link seems to be dead.

Comment: It's worth mentioning https://archive.org/ who try to make a backup of the internet, and you can search for historical versions of dead links on their Wayback Machine.

Comment: damn looks like this link is actually broke: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/check-dependencies-in-grunt-by-default.html although I disagree with copying in much content from links, give the blog author the traffic