# Check versions in package json against actual node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, semantic-versioning

Imagine the situation:

We have a project with `node_modules` gitignored. While fixing a task **developer1** updated `package.json` to newer version of some module, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
  "async": "^1.5.2", // was 1.5.1
  ...
```

Then he runned `npm install` locally to get updated module, performed tests, finished task and pushed changes on the server.

**Developer2** pulled changes from server and get app broken because still having previous version of `async` locally (1.5.1). And developer2 can waste a huge amount of time finding what's exactly goes wrong. Until they do `npm i`.

Can you suggest any npm package or ready-to-use hook that can check versions in `package.json` against actual versions of `node_modules` ?

It will be really helpful!

PS: I'm aware of https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check but it does not do what I need.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: My question is not exactly about tool, but any script or ready-to-use gist is appreciated. I've updated question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to easily verify correct npm dependencies installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915698/how-to-easily-verify-correct-npm-dependencies-installed)

Answer (score 3):

The package [check-dependencies](https://github.com/mgol/check-dependencies) might do what you want.

```
$ check-dependencies
url-loader: installed: 0.5.8, expected: 0.4.0
Invoke npm install to install missing packages
```

Answer (score 0):

At my current day job we had exactly this problem.
We fixed it by creating an easy script that pulled the new source and after that directly executes npm update.