# Quick and dirty way to determine if node_modules needs a re-install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a quick and dirty way to determine if node_modules does not match package.json? In other words, is there a way to check to see if `npm install` needs to be run? This is just an optimization for a developer tools library, but could save users some time if `npm install` does not need to be run.

I don't think this is possible - the only way to know for sure if node_modules is in the right state is to run `npm install`.

Comment: pretty sure this will serve your purpose https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to easily verify correct npm dependencies installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915698/how-to-easily-verify-correct-npm-dependencies-installed)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the optimum solution for what you are looking for:

- [check-dependencies](https://github.com/mgol/check-dependencies)
- [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

for: check-dependencies

**Installation:**

```
$ npm install check-dependencies --save-dev
```

**Usage:**

```
require('check-dependencies')(callback);
```

For: npm-check

**Installation:**

```
$ npm install -g npm-check
```

**Usage:**

```
$ npm-check
```