# Identify missing imports/require npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json, npm-package

I recently encountered an error where the package was getting resolved through some transitive dependency. And when some of these dependencies got updated my code started breaking as the import/require for that dependency was missing in my code.

Can you please suggest an utility or any hook which will validate all imports against package.json. So any of such mistakes can be identified before the code is getting committed or released.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to easily verify correct npm dependencies installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915698/how-to-easily-verify-correct-npm-dependencies-installed)

Comment: Not really . I am looking for a solution where imports in code would also be tracked in package.json so that any transitive dependency resolutions would be avoided.